# What is the name of the black translucent notification window?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

What is the name of the feature that displays a black transparent notification (often only a few seconds in iOS. It shows for example when you switch the mute button on the phone.

Comment: One that is similar to Toast in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently developers don't have access to such notification effects from the official SDK. But you may try this, MBProgressHUD, https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD . It's a third party tool, but it works well and looks good.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a HUD (Heads Up Display).